# Making responsive Bokeh plots with gridplot in Django

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to embed 6 scatter plots using Bokeh (0.12.6) and Django using gridplot, to show 2 rows and 3 columns. They are 6 identical plots, made with very simple code like this (variable names are different):

```
plot1 = figure(
    x_axis_label="Voltage",
    y_axis_label="Time",
    responsive= True
)

plot1.line(json["voltage"],
           json["time"],
           color="red",
           legend="One"
           )

...
grid = gridplot([[plot1, plot2, plot3], 
                 [plot4, plot5, plot6]])
script, div = components(grid)
```

However, the resulting plots are not responsive. They extend horizontally beyond the page limit and do not resize with the browser window. I tried using *sizing_mode* but it didn't have any effect.

Is there a way to force them to fit into the page/container (template uses Bootstrap)?

Comment: I am also still interested in a solution. Maybe one really has to make a separate mobile page and use a different grid there?

Comment: I could not find a solution, so I moved to Plotly.js.